# Render to texture in OpenGL ES 2.0 with iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I'm having a hard time trying to setup a render to texture environment in OpenGL ES 2.0.

What I need is a main FrameBuffer that is presented to screen and a secondary FrameBuffer that is connected to a Texture. This texture is then used in the main FrameBuffer.

I first initialize the main FrameBuffer with this code:

```
-(void)initializeBuffers{

    //Build the main FrameBuffer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

    //Build the color Buffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

    //setup the color buffer with the EAGLLayer (it automatically defines width and height of the buffer)
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:EAGLLayer];
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &bufferWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &bufferHeight);

    //Attach the colorbuffer to the framebuffer
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

    //Check the Framebuffer status
    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

    NSAssert(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, ERROR_FRAMEBUFFER_FAIL);

}
```

Then I call a function to initialise the Secondary Buffer

```
-(void)setupRenderToTexture{

    glGenTextures(1, &gridTextureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gridTextureID);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &textureColorBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, textureColorBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &textureFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, textureFrameBuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gridTextureID, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, textureColorBuffer);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Buffer ok");
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

}
```

At this point, when it is time to draw, I call a function called `render` that calls the function `renderToTexture`:

```
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displaylink{

    [self renderToTexture];

    glBindBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

    glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glViewport(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    for(GLNode *node in sceneNodes){
        [node draw]; //Draw some triangles...
    }

    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Here the `renderToTexture` function:
-(void)renderToTexture{

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, textureFrameBuffer);

glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glViewport(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//Render something to texture
```

}

If I use only the code related with the main buffer (so the functions `initializeBuffers` and `render`) the content of the main FrameBuffer is correctly displayed at screen. If I try to use the functions related with render to texture (`setupRenderToTexture` and `renderToTexture`) the main Framebuffer is no longer drawn at screen.

I wonder if this configuration has something wrong and what can I do to correct this behaviour.